# C++ error: too many initializers for 'int [2]'

Tags: c++, arrays

I keep getting this error when declaring an int[2] array, but it looks fine to me.

```
error: too many initializers for 'int [2]'
 int <array_name>[2] = { 0, 255, 255 };
                                     ^
```

am I doing someting wrong?

Comment: You are probably confusing the max index an array can take, with its size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared the size of array is 2 but gave it 3 elements, I think just change it to int <array_name>[3] will fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

You declare the array to have two elements with `[2]`, but you're trying to assign three numbers to it with `{ 0, 255, 255 }`. Something's gotta give.